# how to fix No reverse match "password _reset_done"?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-urls, password-recovery

i am new to Django, so since yesteday, I keep having problem with the No reverse match in the password reset done. I don't know what is the problem. whenever I visit the" 127.0.0.1:8000/reset-password", it says no reverse match. please help me.

this is the urs.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout, password_reset, 
  password_reset_done

app_name='blog'
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.home,name='home-blog'),
url(r'^About/',views.About ,name='About'),
url(r'^register/',views.register, name='register'),

url(r'^login/$',login,{'template_name':'blog/login.html'}),
url(r'^logout/$',logout,{'template_name':'blog/logout.html'}),
url(r'^reset-password/$',password-reset, name='password-reset'),
url(r'^reset-password/done/$',password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
```

]

Comment: There is a space in the error given in the title, this could be the problem

Comment: **@lain Shelvington** no that was my typo.

Comment: Can you share the traceback?

Comment: Consider removing the `name=` options, and then gather more diagnostic information.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like a problem in `127.0.0.1:8000/reset-password`

or in other words your `url(r'^reset-password/$',password-reset, name='password-reset'),`
multiple attributes are missing like `success_url =`

> form my latest project (but i using Django 2.2.4):

```
from django.urls import path, reverse_lazy
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name='account'

    urlpatterns = [

<....>

    # -- Password Reset
path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
    template_name='password/password_reset.html',
    email_template_name='password/emails/password_reset_email.html',
    subject_template_name='password/emails/password_reset_subject.txt',
     success_url = reverse_lazy('account:password_reset_done'),
    ), 
    name='password_reset'),

<....>
]
```